# JPA. Hibernate как описать запрос?

Tags: java, hibernate

У меня есть запрос в MySQL

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS allbydate;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE allbydate (INDEX a (a,b,c)) AS (select a, b, c from table1);
SELECT a,b,c FROM allbydate;
```

т.е. смысл запроса, чтоб в рамках одной транзакции создавалась временная таблица allbydate, а из нее формировались объекты Test

Есть класс Test.class

```
@NamedQuery(name = Test.GET_LAST, query ="???как правильно выполнить запрос???"),
})

@Entity
@Table(name = "TestDatabase")
public class Test {
    public static final String GET_LAST = "Test.getLast";

    @Id
    @Column(name = "a")
    private String a;

    @Column(name = "b")
    private String b;

    @Column(name = "c")
    private String c;

    public Test() {
    }
}
```

Я не могу понять как создать NamedQuery с несколькими последовательными запросами...

Comment: "...с несколькими последовательными запросами." - транзакции в помощь.

Comment: Рекомендуете выделить это в метод в репозитории и пометить метод @Transactional с соответствующими параметрами?

Comment: я не знаком с hibernate, я лишь говорю что в последовательных запросах есть смысл использовать тразакции.

Comment: я хочу понять, можно ли связать entity с результатом последовательных запросов...

Comment: Запрос такого типа нельзя пихать в аннотацию.

Comment: @RomanC а куда?

Comment: Ну можно создать триггер, ведь это не SQL?

Comment: @RomanC вот сейчас я не понял ))) это MySQL запрос, какой триггер?

Comment: Вообще, я уже сделал через отдельный метод в репозитории. Сейчас только разберусь, какие параметры @Transactional к этому методу нужны...

Comment: Просто думал, можно запрос в NamedQuery запихнуть

Comment: А чего тут непонятного mysql, можно запрос написать, просто если использовать batch запрос, то скрипт можно разбить на несколько запросов, только вот проблема с установкой транзакции так и не решается даже если установить автоматический комитет.

Comment: А зачем сохранять все в БД, если оно там тут же удаляется? Может лучше обойтись данными в памяти и списком.

Comment: @Orthodox Я читал, что из БД данные нужно извлекать в виде, максимально приближенном к готовому. Т.е. выборку и фильтрацию данных производить по максимуму на стороне БД. Тот запрос, что я привел здесь - это сильно упрощенный. Реальный запрос состоит из нескольких этажей таких таблиц. А поиск происходит по БД с количеством записей 1млн+. Поэтому, тянуть это все в память, чтоб делать какие-то вычисления не правильно.

Comment: Я спросил зачем все сохранять в БД и тут же удалять, сохраняя и удаляя таблицу. БД нужна для долговременного хранения. Если Вы все делаете в коротком сеансе сохранять в БД не нужно.

Comment: @Orthodox да там с join'ами вообще такой запрос получается... и его читать сложно... + у меня запрос с временными таблицами исполняется в разы быстрее, чем с join'ами (но это, наверное, вопрос к моим познаниям MySQL)

Comment: Я так понял Вы этот вопрос решили. Хотя мне непонятно зачем Вам вообще нужны временные таблицы?

Comment: Я выше ответил.